# How to implement transactions in an application based on MVC4 / EF 6+

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, transactions

I have just read about [`TransactionScope`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope#hLocalTrans). It is very good and informative.

First of all, I was wondering if I really need transactions in MVC 4 / EF 6+. The reason for that is we always invoke `DbContext.SaveChanges()` to save changes. I'm wondering if `SaveChanges()` is something that simulates transaction close meaning if I invoke `SaveChanges()` I commit a transactions.

On the other hand, if I need transactions, then how to implement `TransactionScope` in MVC / EF applications. My scenario is something similar to the steps below:

- I save valid record in database
- I save a copy of an old and a new record in another table which is sort of  archived version of the original table
- I save user's activity in another table

I also provided code. As you can see if something goes wrong in the middle I have inconsistent data. I would be grateful for some examples on how to use `TransactionScope`. I may also need more to save in other tables. I would like to be certain either I save everything or nothing, such that I save everything if transaction is OK or roll back anything that happened up to the problem.

Thanks.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ApplicationViewModel viewmodel)
{
    using(MyDbCOntext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        if(!MoselState.IsValid)
            return View(application);

        // Copy old data from database and assign to an object
        ApplicationArchive applicationOld = CopyApplicationFromDB(db, viewmodel.ApplicationID);

        // Update model
        if (TryUpdateModel(applicationNew), null, null, new string[] { "ApplicationID" })
        {
            try
            {
                dbContext.Entry(userToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();

                // Archive old application
                ApplicationArchive applicationNew = CopyApplicationFromDB(db, viewmodel.ApplicationID);
                try
                {
                    dbContext.ApplicationsArchive.Add(applicationOld);
                    dbCOntext.ApplicationsArchive.Add(applicationNew);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                    // Register user activity
                    string username = GetUserNameFromCookie();
                    UserActivity useractivity = new UserActivity() { UserName = username, activity = "edit", Table = "application" };
                    try
                    {
                        dbContext.UserActivities.Add(useractivity);
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();

                        return RedirectView("Index");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot update this application");
            }
        }


        //

        return View(application);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Comment: Don't confuse `Transaction` with `TransactionScope`, they are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Maarten I did nto know I was confusing these two. I though `TransactionScope` would facilitate database transactions. This is why I've used both terms here.

Comment: @danludwig Thanks for the link. I am going to read through it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your database operation within a DbContextTransaction. See this link for Entity Framework transaction examples: 
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Comment: Thanks Gregg for the link, although it is the exactly the same as Maarten has provided before.